What is the best action if a reviewer did not read my work (survey paper) but still advised me to cite at least ten of his works?
So I'm talking about a survey paper on a very specific topic. This reviewer suggested that I include hyperparameter training and a comparison with the SOTA model, indicating that he did not read my work because it was a survey paper with no model proposed. However, he suggested at least 10 of his works, some of which are not even relevant. I appreciate the recommendation to make my work more complete, but I believe it should be based on the topic relevance and significance of the recommended work rather than his personal recommendation. What would be the best action? I know citing 2-3 more papers to avoid trouble is fine, but not 10 papers from 1 person with some of them off-topic.

Just do it and add an acknowledgment thanking a referee for pointing out refs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 10. without using them in the paper. People will understand.

Response to reviewers comments

This reviewer suggested that I include hyperparameter training and a comparison with the SOTA model, indicating that he did not read my work because it.  aAs a survey paper with no model proposed, this does not seem appropriate.


However, he They also suggested at least 10 additionsl of his works, some of which are not even
relevant. I appreciate the recommendation to make my work more
complete, but I believe it should be based on the topic relevance and
significance of the recommended work rather than his personal recommendation. I also noted that the recommended work all share an author in common.  We apologise for missing the work of this author and have included the subset of these references we feel relevant to the work.

